# Restricting a text box to enter only numeric values and not alphabetical & alphanumeric values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 text boxes viz. txt_Long and txt_Lat. I want that only numeric values be able to be inserted into those text boxes and not numeric or alphanumeric values. If tried to insert any other values except numeric value, a validation violation message should be displayed in red color just under the respective text boxes.Can any one please help ?

Comment: find for jquery numeric boxes and you will have your solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `compare validator` to check the value entered is number or not .

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox" 
     Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Double" ErrorMessage="Value must be a number">   
 </asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: I am doing just what you said.. but I am getting the error as--   Element 'CompareValidator' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.

Comment: @Debranjan is your web.config present ?

Comment: @Debranjan I have just checked it. Its working fine at my side. Please check that your we.config is present at the root of your application. :)

Comment: Yes sir, it is present

Comment: can you please assist how to check whether web.config is present or not?

Comment: @Debranjan can you please clean your project and Build it, and check is it happening in every project or in particular project. For just a test, make a test project and simply include my code in `Default.aspx` and see if its working.

Comment: @Debranjan make a test project and at very first step doing antything else try my code. If still you are facing the same error, set your VS settings. Here is the link. http://ruchirac.blogspot.com/2012/06/reset-visual-studio-user-settings.html

Comment: the closing tag </asp:CompareValidator> is showing an error: The text property of <asp:textbox does not allow child objects>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regular Expression Validator` like below.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
ErrorMessage="Please Enter Only Numbers" ValidationExpression="^\d+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a normal html5 input you can solve your problem very quickly:

```
<input type="number" id="only-numbers" min="0">
```

It will also show an error automatically if a wrong value is inserted.